# How to get public redirectURL of chrome extensions for oauth?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use the Spotify API which requires a redirecturl for oauth. Is there a way to get a redirect url for the extension? I've been trying : https://[extension-id].chromiumapp.org/

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure i understood your question 100%. Have you tried the Chrome Identity API getAuthToken API for the extensions that cant perform redirects?

see this:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity!